# Another version of the Poincaré Recurrence Theorem (Proof)

Tags: measure-theory, proof-verification

The task is to prove the following version of Poincaré's Recurrence Theorem:

> > Let $(X,\Sigma,\mu)$ be a finite measure space, $f\colon X\to X$ a measurable transformation that preserves the measure, i.e. $\mu(f^{-1}(E))=\mu(E)$ for all $E\in\Sigma$. Then for any $E\in\Sigma$ it is
> >     $$
> > \mu(\left\{x\in E|\left\{f^n(x)\right\}_{n>0}\subset X\setminus E\right\}=0,
> > $$
> >     i.e. almost every point in $E$ returns to $E$ infinitely often.

Here is my **Proof.**
$$
\tilde{E}:=\left\{x\in E|\left\{f^n(x)\right\}_{n>0}\subset X\setminus E\right\}=E\cap\left(\bigcap_{n>0}f^{-n}(X\setminus E)\right)
$$
$\tilde{E}$ is measurable, because $E$ is measurable, $f^{-n}(E^C)$ is measurable for each $n>0$ (as composition of measurable functions), and therefore $\bigcap_{n>0}f^{-n}(X\setminus E)$ and $\tilde{E}$ are measurable.

Furthermore it is
$$
f^{-n}(\tilde{E})\cap\tilde{E}=\emptyset~\forall~n>0,
$$
because let $x\in f^{-n}(\tilde{E})$, then $f^n(x)\in\tilde{E}\subset E$, but for all $x\in\tilde{E}$ it is $f^n(x)\in X\setminus E$.

Consider $n,m>0$ and w.l.o.g. $n>m$. Then it is
$$
f^{-n}(\tilde{E})\cap f^{-m}(\tilde{E})=f^{-m}(f^{-(n-m)}(\tilde{E})\cap\tilde{E})=f^{-m}(\emptyset)=\emptyset.
$$
So using the measure properties of $\mu$, the finiteness of $\mu$ and that $f$ preserves the measure it is 
$$
\infty > \mu(X)\geqslant \mu\left(\biguplus_{n>0}f^{-n}(\tilde{E})\right)=\sum_{n>0}\mu(f^{-n}(\tilde{E}))=\sum_{n>0}\mu(\tilde{E}).
$$
Because $\mu(\tilde{E})\geq 0$ it follows that $\mu(\tilde{E})=0$, because otherwise $\sum_{n>0}\mu(\tilde{E})<\infty$ would be impossible.

---

That's it. Is my proof right?

Would be great to get a feedback!

Sincerely yours,

math12

Comment: Maybe you'd like to declare the statement you are using? Currently I am reading Barreira & Valls' book, and they start with the statement you want to prove as the recurrence theorem.

Comment: Well done proof.

Answer (score 1):

This is an old question, but let me give an answer.

Your proof is quite fine (that's your question). On the other hand, both your statement and proof are really what is accepted to be the canon of Poincaré's recurrence theorem, and all introductory books of ergodic theory should have it.

*A complement:* Another question, which turned out to be much more difficult, is whether Poincaré recurrence can be quantified, that is, whether one can say something about the speed with which the orbits recur to a given set of positive measure. For details about this, I recommend Barreira's book Dimension and Recurrence in Hyperbolic Dynamics, Chapter 15.