# Poincare' recurrence theorem in measure theory.

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

I want to propose a problem, it's a version of Poincare' Recurrence Theorem, it's very similar to another problem proposed in this forum, but a bit different:
[Another version of the Poincaré Recurrence Theorem (Proof)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/866166/another-version-of-the-poincar%C3%A9-recurrence-theorem-proof)
The problem is this: Let $(X,\mathcal{A},\mu)$ a measure space such that $\mu(X)<\infty$. Let $T:X\to X$ a map such that:

1)$T(E)\in \mathcal{A},\:\forall E\in \mathcal{A}$.

2) $\mu(T(E))=\mu(E),\:\forall E\in \mathcal{A}$.

Prove that $\forall E\in \mathcal{A}$
$$\mu(\{x\in E\;\; s.t.\; x\notin T^n(E)\text{ definitively}\})=0$$
Saying it in another way
$$\mu(E\setminus \limsup_{n\to\infty}T^n(E))=\mu(\bigcup_{k=1}^\infty (E\setminus\bigcup_{n=k}^\infty T^n(E)))=0$$
Notice that $\displaystyle \bigcup_{k=1}^\infty (E\setminus\bigcup_{n=k}^\infty T^n(E))\subseteq
\bigcup_{k=1}^\infty (T^{k-1}(E)\setminus\bigcup_{n=k}^\infty T^n(E))$

So if we prove that for all $E$ measurable $\displaystyle \mu(E\setminus\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty T^n(E))=0$ we have concluded. Suppose that it's not true. Let $E$ measurable and $F:=E\setminus\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty T^n(E)$. Then by definition it happens that $T^n(F)\cap F=\emptyset,\;n\in\mathbb{N^+}$. I want to prove that actually $T^n(F)\cap T^m(F)=\emptyset$ or at least it has measure equal to 0. The idea is "apply"T to the previous equality but in general $T(A\cap B)=T(A)\cap T(B)$ only if $T$ is injective.
Otherwise i should prove that $\mu(T(A)\cap T(B))=\mu(T(A\cap B))$ under these hypothesis, but it's not simple.

Comment: What does "$x\not\in T^n(E)$ definitively" mean? That it holds for sufficiently large $n$?

Comment: $\exists k$ such that $x\notin T^n(E)$ for all $n\geq k$

Comment: For future reference, the word you wanted was "eventually".

Comment: You must use $\mu (X)<\infty$ or it can't be done.For example with Lebesgue measure on the reals with $T(F)=F+1=\{x+1: x\in F\}$, and with $E=[0,1).$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would like to prove that, $\forall E\in \mathcal{A}$,

$$\mu(E\setminus \limsup_{n\to\infty}T^n(E))=\mu\left (\bigcup_{k=1}^\infty \left(E\setminus\bigcup_{n=k}^\infty T^n(E)\right)\right)=0$$

Let us prove by contradiction. Suppose

$$\mu\left (\bigcup_{k=1}^\infty \left(E\setminus\bigcup_{n=k}^\infty T^n(E)\right)\right)>0$$

Then there is $k\geqslant 1$ such that

$$\mu\left (E\setminus\bigcup_{n=k}^\infty T^n(E)\right)>0$$

Since $\mu(X)<\infty$, we have

$$ \mu\left (E\cup\bigcup_{n=k}^\infty T^n(E)\right)>\mu\left (\bigcup_{n=k}^\infty T^n(E)\right)$$

Since $\mu(T(E))=\mu(E),\:\forall E\in \mathcal{A}$, applying $T$ $k$ times, we get

$$\mu\left (T^k(E)\cup\bigcup_{n=2k}^\infty T^n(E)\right)= 
\mu\left (T^k\left( E\cup\bigcup_{n=k}^\infty T^n(E)\right)\right)=
\mu\left (E\cup\bigcup_{n=k}^\infty T^n(E)\right) 
>\mu\left (\bigcup_{n=k}^\infty T^n(E)\right)$$

**Contradition**, because 
$$ T^k(E)\cup\bigcup_{n=2k}^\infty T^n(E) \:\subseteq \: \bigcup_{n=k}^\infty T^n(E)$$

Comment: Very nice. You had a small typo. I fixed it. ("Applying $T$ $k$").